# SLES 15 SP4: snapper.service is being run, but no timeline snapshot is created

Tags: snapshot, suse

I have to new installations using SLES15 SP4, and I have an older SLES15 SP3 installation that was upgraded from SLES12 SP5.

While the older installation created "timeline" snapshots every hour, the newer installations do not, and I wonder: *Why?*.

AFAIR I did not change the snapper configuration from the default, and I verified that the `snapper-timeline.timer` triggers and the `snapper-timeline.service` is started, and it exists with `status=0/success`.
Still, no timeline snapshot is being created, while the other `number` snapshots (e.g. from yast online_update) are being created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by editing `/etc/snapper/configs/root`:
The older system had

```text
TIMELINE_CREATE="yes"
TIMELINE_CLEANUP="yes"
```

while the new system had (among other settings)

```text
TIMELINE_CREATE="no"
TIMELINE_CLEANUP="yes"
```

So I just enabled timeline creation (and adjusted some numbers like `TIMELINE_LIMIT_YEARLY`).